# How to use voice as command in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, voice, voice-recognition

I am having trouble in writing a code in my speech recognition engine.
The task is, when the user says 'circle', the engine should automatically draw a circle on the form:

```
if(Speech == circle)
{
    DrawCircle();
}
```

The code I'm using for speech recognition is...

```
namespace speechexampl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SpeechRecognizer rec = new SpeechRecognizer();

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;

        }


        void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblLetter.Text = e.Result.Text;
        }

        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             var c = new Choices();
             for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++)

             c.Add(i.ToString());

             var gb = new GrammarBuilder(c);

             var g = new Grammar(gb);

             rec.LoadGrammar(g);

             rec.Enabled = true;

         }
     }
}

//**

//> and to draw circle or rectangle:

//**

Pen myPen2 = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
Rectangle myRectangle2 = new Rectangle(95, 130, 100, 100);
graphicsObj.DrawEllipse(myPen2, myRectangle2);
```

I don't know how to merge the above code to execute a circle when said so. Any related answer would be a great help!

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: Your `rec_SpeechRecognized` event handler isn't doing anything to do with circles. You need to put your check for "circle" and the corresponding call to `DrawCircle()` within there...

Comment: To the "-1"-Clicker: Please tell him why you click "-1", he is new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.Result.Text` will give you what the person said. So if you want to draw a circle when they say `"circle"`:

```
if (e.Result.Text == "circle") {
    //Draw a cricle
}
```

Comment: I've no idea about this class - but is it safer to do `e.Result.Text.ToLower()`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just didn't say so. ;)

Comment: I'm sure they'll figure it out :)

Comment: @annonymously.... omg it worked... i was hel tensed since last 3 days jus beacause this line of code :) thankyou very very very very very much for the help, i ll remember always, you jus carried me outta hell :) thanks